# Alamofire (URL) request fail after come back from another app ex: Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlsession

Calling any API in my app directly after my app come to foreground (for example: after login via Facebook)

Alamofire localized error:

```
Operation couldn't be completed. Software caused connection abort
```

Comment: I had this issue before. Alamofire Github issues says it's a Background problem.. but actually, if you use `NSURLSession` directly, it works.. so not sure :l You can try that instead.

Comment: @Brandon, yess it seems to be an apple bug, i found a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an apple bug, because someone reproduced it also using URLSessionManager. here is a simple a workaround:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {

        // your API request 

}
```